# HAProxy send-proxy to Nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, haproxy, pfsense, synology

I am trying to reverse proxy clients to a web server through HAProxy and Nginx with SSL traffic using SNI. With the standard configuration, the web server sees the HAProxy IP and connects. When applying "send-proxy" to the appropriate backend in HAproxy my client browser fails to connect and times out. How can I configure Nginx headers to decipher this and the web server know their IP?

Answer (score 1):

See [NGINX's docs](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/using-proxy-protocol/):

```
http {
    #...
    server {
        listen 80   proxy_protocol;
        listen 443  ssl proxy_protocol;
        #...
    }
}
```

This allows NGINX to be downstream from an HAProxy transmitting proxy protocol. The link I quoted contains more information on how to log/get the client's IP address.

Comment: This works, although I had to also enable transparent clientIP in HAProxy with "source ipv4@ usesrc clientip".